Extract lines from the image with text
I have followde the image:

I want to extract only lines from it -- only lines without text.
What would be the best practice to do this?
I tried with the cv2 Python library and HoughLinesP with following the code:
img = cv2.imread('/Users/tekija/Documents/image.png')
img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
img_thr = cv2.threshold(img_gray, 120, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(
img_thr, rho=1, theta=np.pi / 180, threshold=128, minLineLength=600, maxLineGap=30)
lines = lines.squeeze()

but results are:


Are the lines always the same color?

Are the lines always colored and not black? If so, you can use the saturation from HSV to find them typically

Alternately, get contours and filter on length to discard the short ones from the characters.

Was this useful: A good approach for detecting lines in an image?

@DaSt yes,Lines are always same color. Dirrerent than the text of polygons.

@fmw42 Yes, lines are always colored, but color is not unique for each image.

@user2727167 So try converting to HSV and looking at the Saturation channel. You should be able to threshold to extract the lines only. You may need to do some morphology to remove small spots left from the text or get contours and throw out small lengths.

this is in the context of a GIS application, isn't it. whoever provides those pictures can also give you the source GIS data

Since you have confirmed that the lines always have the same color, it makes sense to first filter by this color and then detect the lines.
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Load image
image = cv2.imread('demo.png')

# Convert to HSV
hsv_image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

# Define color range (original is #7e3553)
lower_range = np.array([155, 100, 20])
upper_range = np.array([175, 255, 255])

# Create mask
mask = cv2.inRange(hsv_image, lower_range, upper_range)

# Dilate the mask to fill in small gaps
mask = cv2.dilate(mask, (3,3), iterations=2)

# Detect points that form a line
lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(mask, 1, np.pi/180, 100, minLineLength=10, maxLineGap=250)

# Draw lines on new mask
line_mask = np.zeros(image.shape[:2], dtype=np.uint8)
for line in lines:
    x1, y1, x2, y2 = line[0]
    cv2.line(line_mask, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), 255, 3)

# Erode to thin the lines
line_mask = cv2.erode(line_mask, (3,3), iterations=2)

cv2.imwrite('demo_output.png', line_mask)

This is the result, notice how all the gaps at the top and bottom right are closed:


I just slightly modified your code.
Added inversion and changed parameters.
import cv2
import numpy as np
img = cv2.imread('lines.png')
img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
img_thr = cv2.threshold(img_gray, 120, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)[1]
lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(img_thr, rho=1, theta=np.pi / 180/30, threshold=60, minLineLength=150, maxLineGap=4)
lines = lines.squeeze()
for i in range(lines.shape[0]):
    cv2.line(img, (lines[i,0], lines[i,1]), (lines[i,2], lines[i,3]), (255,0,0),2)
cv2.imwrite('lines_out.png', img)



I like your improvement, but it misses a part at the bottom right of the image

Try correct minLineLength parameter.
